# match files using python

Tags: python

I have 2 text files

File 1.txt

```
ACVR2B

ASCL2

.

.

.

.
```

file2.txt

```
>
ACVR2B:chr3:38309062 [-1000..50](+) [human, Homo sapiens]
cacttggttgggtttaaatgaccactccccgccctagctgtgcctttgag
tgtgtggcaagggattgcagacgggagactgcttgtcaattcagggaagt
cagcctctttctgccacttaattcgcccatcagtagagatccgactttcc
cacggttcactgtcacccccattgcacaggtggggaatccaaggcacaga
ggcgtctgggccagagtcccgggactatccactcattccggggttgtagg
gcagcatgtgtcaggagcttgggctcgagcgtgcggggcactaattgcga
gtgcagtggccacaggctcccgggcaaagtggtcaggagcccattcccgc
cacctccgtccgcgcgccccgccctgtcctccagcaagttggtgcacgcg
cgtcctcccacagggcgcgggatgggggcggggcctccgtgttgttgttt
ctctggggccccgcccctcaggggggcgcggaccacgcggccggagggcc
cgcctcccctccccctccccgcccagcccgcccgcctctttgtatccaac
atccgggtttccccgctggctcggctccgtggccgccgctcaggagccat
tttggactcggttcagctcccctcccccccacccctccccccgttcatgg
cccctccggactcggcccctgcgcccggggcccgggcccagccccgccgc
gctatgcctgagtcgggcgcgccccggcccgtgccccgccgccgcccccc
ggcccccgcgtcgccccggagcccgggccgcagcctgcgccgcccgcagc
ggccctgagcccggccccgccgaccggcccttggagcccgaacgctgctc

>
ASCL2:chr11:2250253 [-1000..50](-) [human, Homo sapiens]
ggccttacagaatgtgatcgcgcgagggggagggcgaagcgtggcgggag
ggcgaggcgaaggaaggagggcgtgagaaaggcgacggcggcggcgcgga
ggagggttatctatacatttaaaaaccagccgcctgcgccgcgcctgcgg
agacctgggagagtccggccgcacgcgcgggacacgagcgtcccacgctc
cctggcgcgtacggcctgccaccactaggcctcctatccccgggctccag
acgacctaggacgcgtgccctggggagttgcctggcggcgccgtgccaga
agcccccttggggcgccacagttttccccgtcgcctccggttcctctgcc
tgcaccttcctgcggcgcgccgggacctggagcgggcgggtggatgcagg
cgcgatggacggcggcacactgcccaggtccgcgccccctgcgccccccg
tccctgtcggctgcgctgcccggcggagacccgcgtccccggaactgttg
cgctgcagccggcggcggcgaccggccaccgcagagaccggaggcggcgc
agcggccgtagcgcggcgcaatgagcgcgagcgcaaccgcgtgaagctgg
tgaacttgggcttccaggcgctgcggcagcacgtgccgcacggcggcgcc
agcaagaagctgagcaaggtggagacgctgcgctcagccgtggagtacat
ccgcgcgctgcagcgcctgctggccgagcacgacgccgtgcgcaacgcgc
tggcgggagggctgaggccgcaggccgtgcggccgtctgcgccccgcggg
ccgccagggaccaccccggtcgccgcctcgccctcccgcgcttcttcgtc
cccgggccgcgggggcagctcggagcccggctccccgcgttccgcctact
cgtcggacgacagcggctgcgaaggcgcgctgagtcctgcggagcgcgag
ctactcgacttctccagctggttagggggctactgagcgccctcgaccta
tgaggtaacagccgggaggcagggaggagggagggccgggggccggggtg
ggggacgaaggcgcaggaagcgcgcagggaacgagaccgaaggaaggagc
gggaaggagagcgcagccgccgcctggccctgcgcgccccgggagcgccg
tgcggccctgcccgcgggctccgggtgtgcgcggggcggcgccgcggaac
atgacggcgccctgggtggccctcgccctcctctggggatcgctgtgcgc
.
.
.
.
.
```

Now my task is to write python script to match file 1 with file 2 if word from file 1 is there in file 2 then it should print all data file 2 as example

if ASCL2 from file 1 is there in file 2 then it should give result as follows

```
>
ASCL2:chr11:2250253 [-1000..50](-) [human, Homo sapiens]
ggccttacagaatgtgatcgcgcgagggggagggcgaagcgtggcgggag
ggcgaggcgaaggaaggagggcgtgagaaaggcgacggcggcggcgcgga
ggagggttatctatacatttaaaaaccagccgcctgcgccgcgcctgcgg
agacctgggagagtccggccgcacgcgcgggacacgagcgtcccacgctc
cctggcgcgtacggcctgccaccactaggcctcctatccccgggctccag
acgacctaggacgcgtgccctggggagttgcctggcggcgccgtgccaga
agcccccttggggcgccacagttttccccgtcgcctccggttcctctgcc
tgcaccttcctgcggcgcgccgggacctggagcgggcgggtggatgcagg
cgcgatggacggcggcacactgcccaggtccgcgccccctgcgccccccg
tccctgtcggctgcgctgcccggcggagacccgcgtccccggaactgttg
cgctgcagccggcggcggcgaccggccaccgcagagaccggaggcggcgc
agcggccgtagcgcggcgcaatgagcgcgagcgcaaccgcgtgaagctgg
tgaacttgggcttccaggcgctgcggcagcacgtgccgcacggcggcgcc
agcaagaagctgagcaaggtggagacgctgcgctcagccgtggagtacat
ccgcgcgctgcagcgcctgctggccgagcacgacgccgtgcgcaacgcgc
tggcgggagggctgaggccgcaggccgtgcggccgtctgcgccccgcggg
ccgccagggaccaccccggtcgccgcctcgccctcccgcgcttcttcgtc
cccgggccgcgggggcagctcggagcccggctccccgcgttccgcctact
cgtcggacgacagcggctgcgaaggcgcgctgagtcctgcggagcgcgag
ctactcgacttctccagctggttagggggctactgagcgccctcgaccta
tgaggtaacagccgggaggcagggaggagggagggccgggggccggggtg
ggggacgaaggcgcaggaagcgcgcagggaacgagaccgaaggaaggagc
gggaaggagagcgcagccgccgcctggccctgcgcgccccgggagcgccg
tgcggccctgcccgcgggctccgggtgtgcgcggggcggcgccgcggaac
atgacggcgccctgggtggccctcgccctcctctggggatcgctgtgcgc

..
```

Can any body help me

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter with your code?

Comment: Maybe you could first try to use simpler examples.

Comment: Post some code.... What have you tried so far?

Comment: no example code; unclear intention; possible Homework?

Answer (score 0):

First, open file 1 and read it's contents into a set:

```
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    search_set =  set(f.read().split('\n')
```

Then, extract the first part of file 2 and test for membership in the set:

```
f = open('file2.txt', 'r')
test_string = f.readline()

if test_string.split(':')[0] in search_set:
    #There's a match:
    print(test_string + f.read())
else:
    print('no match')

f.close()
```